# How to send a last message after the dialogue is finished

Tags: ibm-watson

I want to create a weather bot
But the user says

I wanna know the temperature in Miami

Now I have the city Miami and I consult the temp using my APIs, then I want to know how can I send this back to Watson using Context variables.

The reason that I want to send the info back to Watson is that 
I want to create several answers to my question. So my bot can look more human.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it at an Application layer, normally the way to approach it is to set a context variable that tells your logic to continue on with the response.

Another approach which may work better is to use the cloud functions to query the weather, then carry on in the dialog tree before returning.